# Hadoop Multinode Cluster installation via Ambari

Tags: hadoop, ambari

For setting multi node cluster in hadoop through ambari does we require similar type of operating system at both the hosts or different will work too.. for eg mine 1 host has cent os 7 and other has cent os 6 so will the setup will be successfull or it will through an error..

Answer (score 0):

I think it not regarding your OS 7 and OS 6, because Hadoop is deployed by master machine and slaves machines, once you have deployed the master nodes, other nodes can direct join the Hadoop cluster. Also, the YARN will responsible for the task scheduling.

Comment: as there are services in hadoop which require only cent os 7 to run so i can install and run that kind of services on cluster having different OS on nodes???

Comment: I do not sure, as distributed systems that should match with different systems and hardware. The Hadoop used the Zookeeper for maintaining the cluster that should strong with fault Torrence and compatibility. So it should be success use OS6 and OS7 to deploy your cluster.

Comment: it gives an error "Cluster primary/cluster OS family is redhat7 and local/current OS family is redhat6"

Answer (score 0):

Ambari supports clusters that consist of heterogeneous OSs. Just make sure to provide valid repo URLs for OSs in use when deploying cluster

[image]